# Unable to remvove products from a category

Tags: php, sql, magento, magento-1.5

In my magento 1.5 I have a category with 800 products. I want to empty it, I tried emptying it from the Manage Category>>Category Products tab.

Then reindexed and flushed the cache.

However the category still shows products on the frontend. On the backend, it shows no products on the "Category Products" tab

I suspect the problem is associated with some category-product association index table. All other categories are behaving normally, and reflect the changes after cache flush. But this particular category doesnt.

If someone could point out what index tables are for what purpose, I could try to do it on the database with SQL.

I know SQL isnt advised, but I have tried all manual/programattic solution.

Comment: Can you check if `Is Anchor` is set to `Yes` in the `Display Settings` tab of the category edit page ?

Comment: yes. Is Anchor is set to Yes. But if I set it to No I would lose the left side bar, wouldnt I?

Comment: Yes, layered navigation only applies to anchor categories, otherwise the left column will only display a navigation menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your category is an anchor, so it will automatically include all the products from its children. Setting `Is Anchor` to `No` in the `Display settings` tab will disable this behaviour.

Comment: thank you :) It solved my problem. All the children category products were also being included :)